# Remove string from input on click? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to write my own function to wrap each string separated by a comma in a tag, I have this working, but on the 'close' click id like to remove the corresponding string from the input, is this possible at all?

**jQuery**

```
$('body').on('click', '.tag span', function(){ 
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
        $('.result').html('');
        var valueArr = $(this).val().split(',');
        for(var i=0; i<valueArr.length; i++){$('.result').append('<div class="tag">'+valueArr[i]+'<span> X</span></div>')};
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Liamatvenn/7huQ4/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always modify your click handler to do something like:

```
$('body').on('click', '.tag span', function(){
    var $this, $input, val, arr;
    $this = $(this);
    $input = $('input');
    arr = $input.val().split(',');
    val = $this.parent().text().replace(' X','');
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(val), 1);
    $input.val(arr.join(',')); 
    $this.parent().hide();
});
```

You can see it working at http://jsfiddle.net/eF5ev/

Comment: Thats great @Justin Niessner! Thanks

Comment: This'll mess up text like `Foo X, Foo Y`.

Comment: @Blender - Actually, it won't. It'll remove the first occurrence of ' X' and leave the second, thus leaving everything in tact. Give it a shot in the Fiddle.

Comment: I think this can be much simplified, and i have this solution which takes care duplicate item too, and doesn't leave comma behind.

Comment: @PSL - I agree, which is why I gave you an up-vote. I've also updated my answer to do something similar with the commas. Not sure about duplicates though...didn't test it. 5 minute code is always going to have some bugs though.

Comment: I dont think the comma should be left behind

Comment: @sipp - I updated prior to your comment to fix the comma issue.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Thank you, thats why i took a little time to ensure it is as he needs but OP had no patience !!!

Comment: @JustinNiessner I see now, +1 from me

Comment: @JustinNiessner another issue using $('input') you might end up selecting some other input in DOM that appears previous to this input. That is why i sepcifically select the input that is relative

Comment: @PSL - Normally I would agree, but the fact that the OP specifically uses it elsewhere in the code indicates that it's the only input on the page. Otherwise the keyup handler would also be too broad. No need to add extra traversal if it's not needed.

Comment: I am sure that will not be the case in his real world scenario... :) Even if so, if he has multiple inputs then `$input.val()` will give the value of the first one. Also what if it is a checkbox input that appears in DOM prior or any other inputs?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.tag span', function(){ 
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $(this).closest('.result').prev('input').val(""); //get the input respective to the clicked close button.
});
```

`.closest()` will get you to the parent `.result` and target only its previous `input` which generated the tag using `.prev()`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtHyD/)**

Much simpler, use index of the clicked tag item and remove that respective item from the array based on the same index as they are inserted in that order itself.

```
$('body').on('click', '.tag span', function () {
    var $parent = $(this).closest('.tag');
    var index = $parent.index(); //Get the index of the `tag`

    $(this).closest('.result').prev('input').val(function (_, value) { //use val function argument
        var values = value.split(','); //split the value
        values.splice(index, 1); //remove the item from array
        return values.join(','); //join them back
    });

    $parent.remove(); //then remove your tag
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KupRD/)**

Comment: Sorry @PSL, I don't think I worded my question correctly, I only want to remove the matching string from the input, not clear the input entirely...

Comment: @Liam oh you mean the tag will have some other string which might be a substring of what is typed in?

Comment: So say in the input you type, "foo, bar" the 2 words would be wrapped in a div tag. When you click the X next to foo, I want 'foo' removing from my input leaving only 'bar'

Comment: @Liam what is use types in same word twice comma separated?

Comment: I hadn't anticipated that yet @PSL so thanks for raising it, still struggling to remove the matching string though...

Comment: @Liam see the solution your issue is addressed with a simpler solution

Comment: +1 for a good solution. I wouldn't say it's simpler though. It requires a lot of unnecessary DOM traversal to get values.

Comment: yeah OP had no patience.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just store your elements in an array and remove the ones that get clicked by their index:

```
var $tag = $('<div class="tag"><span class="text"></span><span class="close">&times;</span></div>');
var tags = [];

$('.result').on('click', '.tag .close', function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    tags.splice($parent.index(), 1);
    $parent.remove();

    $('input').val(tags.join(', '));
});

$('input').keyup(function() {
    tags = []
    $('.result').empty();

    $(this.value.split(/\s*,\s*/)).each(function(index, value) {
        var tag = $tag.clone();

        tag.find('.text').text(value);
        tag.appendTo('.result');

        tags.push(value);
    });
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7huQ4/9/**

Answer (score 0):

You can input data on close button click. jquery text() method to get text inside  tag.
remove that text from input data. then remove leading and trailing commas with regular expression.

Try this one.

```
    $('input').keyup(function(e) {
                var input = $(this); /* Store input object for replaced value insertion */
                $('.result').html('');
                var valueArr = $(this).val().split(',');

                for (var i = 0; i < valueArr.length; i++) {
                    $('.result').append('<div class="tag">' + valueArr[i] + '<span> X</span></div>');
                }
                $('span').click(function() {
                    /* Removal of unwanted string like ' X' (close button) */
                    var data = $(this).parent().text();
                    data = data.replace($(this).text(), ""); /* Basic javascript replace() function*/
                    /* Delete unwanted commas, Store modified string to input field */
                    input.val(input.val().replace(data, '')
                                         .replace(/^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$/g, '')
                                         .replace(/,[,\s]*,/g, ','));
                });
            });
```

[demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7uqEg/](http://jsfiddle.net/7uqEg/)